# Why did USSR lay down undersea communications cable between Petropavlovsk and Vladivostok?

Tags: soviet-union, communication, kamchatka

Why not just use a land cable that goes around the Sea of Okhotsk? A land cable is safer, and tapping it is harder. I screen cap [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Vladivostok,+Primorsky+Krai,+Russia/Petropavlovsk-Kamchatskiy,+Kamchatka+Krai,+Russia/@56.0190135,128.2212446,4z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x5fb39cba5249d485:0x186704d4dd967e35!2m2!1d131.9112975!2d43.1332484!1m5!1m1!1s0x58e199fa624a92cd:0x130f471bcd14a21!2m2!1d158.6320734!2d53.0583997!3e0).
[image]
 I know the undersea cable is more direct, but did it speed up communication that much? [Operation Ivy Bells - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Ivy_Bells).

> In the early 1970s the U.S. government learned of the existence of an undersea communications cable in the [Sea of Okhotsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_of_Okhotsk), which connected the major Soviet Pacific Fleet naval base at [Petropavlovsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky) on the [Kamchatka Peninsula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamchatka_Peninsula) to the Soviet [Pacific Fleet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Fleet_(Russia))'s mainland headquarters at [Vladivostok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladivostok).[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Ivy_Bells#cite_note-SontagDrew2000-2):172 At the time, the Sea of Okhotsk was claimed by the [Soviet Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_Union) as [territorial waters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_waters), and was strictly off limits to foreign vessels, and the Soviet Navy had installed a network of sound detection devices along the seabed to detect intruders. The area also saw numerous surface and subsurface naval exercises.

Comment: Maybe it was cheaper and faster to lay the cable underwater than to string it through what I think is very rugged countryside.

Comment: Do you know _when_ the cable was laid?

Comment: I would challenge you to support your claim that a land cable is safer & harder to tap?  Especially given the sort of detection devices you describe.

Comment: Kamchatka is not easily accessible overland. There's simply no ground connection between Petropavlovsk and Vladivostok: no road, no railway.

Comment: It's not just a bit shorter - it's actually way shorter in terms of distance. Add to this price of   establishing and supporting communication and you'll see that it's actually way cheaper. And actually it's a very common practice -  very often something is wired through water.

Comment: Even in developed zones there are submarine cables connecting points that can also be connected overland (and likely are). For example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BARSAV between Spain and Italy.

Answer (score 5):

Laying a land cable would be prohibitively expensive. The main reason is not the
large distance but the fact that most of this territory is completely undeveloped: it has no roads. If you look at the Google map carefully you see that there is still no roads there. This is a thinly populated wilderness.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion, but the statement about a complete lack of roads is too broad. It _is_ a "thinly populated wilderness", but are some roads -- look in the vicinity of any medium sized town.

Comment: Local roads in the neighborhoods of the settlements do not help in this task.